# How define a string array list?

Tags: c#

I'd like to define a list whose element is a 3-elements array. Below codes seems ok:
`List<dynamic[]> bb = null;`
but when I try:
 `List<dynamic[3]> bb = null;`

It throws error. Sure I can create a class/struct for that. But is there a way to define it directly?

Comment: Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'List<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: Every time i see someone use dynamic i cringe

Comment: Do either of these work `List<dynamic[]> bb1 = new List<dynamic[]> { new dynamic[] { 1, "a", "h" } };
            List<dynamic[]> bb2 = new List<dynamic[]> { new dynamic[3] };`?

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way:

```
var list = new List<string[]>();

list.Add(new string[3] { "1", "2", "3" });
list.Add(new string[2] { "1", "2" });
```

Update:

@Ilya's answer shows a solution with `dynamic`, but I advise you against using `dynamic`. If you know the structure of the objects create a class or use a tuple, e.g.

```
var list = new List<(int id, string name, uint reputation)>();

list.Add((298540, "xiaoyafeng", 11));
list.Add((2707359, "Ilya", 3576));
list.Add((581076, "tymtam", 4421));
list.Add((3043, "Joel Coehoorn", 294378));
```

Comment: I absolutely agree with you! It is better to avoid `dynamic` when it is possible (at least when it is not obvious how to create a list of arrays). The only reason I put `dynamic` in my answer is in using of this in the question.

Comment: It's very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Tuple is the way to go here, I think.

Comment: btw, for the best practice, which one is better?  List<(int id, string name, uint reputation)>  or List<Tuple<int, string, uint>>  ?

Comment: Best practice would probably be a class. Cause eventually you'll use it. But it's hard to know without a _lot_ more context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your issue was; your title talks about a "string array list", but your posted code describes a list of arrays of dynamic.

I'm not sure I'll ever have reason to create a list of arrays of dynamic, but to show that the code that you discussed in your post can work, this works for me:

```
var stuff = new List<dynamic[]>
{
    new dynamic[] {1, "string"},
    new dynamic[] {DateTime.Now, 45.0}
};
```

But, as noted in other answers, dynamic is a great answer to several classes of questions.  But, it's not the right answer here.  The right answer to the title of your question (not the description) will use a list of string arrays (as has been pointed in the other answers:

```
var otherStuff = new List<string[]>
{
    new string[] {"Now", "Is", "the", "time"},
    new string[] {"for all", "good men, etc."}
};
```

Comment: Why the down vote?  I was simply pointing out that the OP's original question (which was muddled) had sample code, and that there is a way to get that sample code to compile.  His question title and his description don't match (the title was about a "string array list", while the code he posted in his was about a list of arrays of dynamic)  If someone searches for a list of array of dynamic, my answer at least shows it's possible.  I'll edit the answer to make it clear what I'm doing.  But, if you down-vote me, at least have the courtesy to tell my I'm crazy - thanks!

Comment: I didn't down vote, but yeah i think it was a little harsh as well, upvote for getting it to work

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need something like this:

```
List<dynamic[]> bb = new List<dynamic[]>();
bb.Add(new dynamic[3]); // here you add a 3-element array
bb.Add(new dynamic[3] { "a", "b", "c" }); // here you add another one 3-element array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// List containing a string array with 3 nulls in it
var aa = new List<string[]> {new string[3]};

// List containing a string array with 3 strings in it
var bb = new List<string[]> {new[] {"a", "b", "c"}};
```